# Discord.py - Count how many servers the bot is in

Tags: python, discord

I know it's something like len.client.servers or len(client.servers) but I can't get it to work.
I am trying to get it to say "I'm in x servers!" when I say ^botservers. All of the other commands work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
if message.content.startswith('^botservers'):
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "I'm in " + len(client.servers) + " servers!")
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually you have it!

Just do this

```
if message.content.startswith('^botservers'):

    await message.channel.send("I'm in " + str(len(client.guilds)) + " servers!")
```

That makes sure you have an str not an int.

Answer (score 1):

It's Not client.servers its client.guilds
Here is my example

```py
if message.content.startswith('^botservers'):
  await message.channel.send( f"I'm in {len(client.guilds)} servers!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Count Guilds!

```py
import discord   

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        count = len(self.guilds)
        print(f'Logged on as {count}, your bot {self.user} !')
        
client = MyClient()
client.run(Token)
```

Answer (score -1):

`len()`returns an integer, and you are trying to concatenate it with a string. You should typecast it with `str()`

```py
if message.content.startswith('^botservers'):
  await client.send_message(message.channel, "I'm in " + str(len(client.servers)) + " servers!")
```

Also, preferably for better design, you should be using the built-in command handler rather the `on_message` event to make commands.

Try the following code:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='^')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def botservers(ctx):
    await client.say("I'm in " + str(len(client.servers)) + " servers")

client.run("token")
```

Comment: `guilds` not `servers`

Comment: @DanA It is servers. His question was pre 1.0 I'm pretty sure when I answered it. It was later changed to guilds.

See: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html

Comment: ahhh Im sorry @Mary